# Map View in a Tab Android

Tags: android

I have been working on this Tab View and I finally got it working and all my icons in just right. I went to place a Map View in one of the Tabs just like I would with any other class. For some reason it is not work when I launch the app, it force closes right away. This is the error from LogCat:

```
11-24 02:06:36.345: E/dalvikvm(1978): Could not find class 'com.nyneaxis.api.gascloud.StationsMap', referenced from method com.nyneaxis.api.gascloud.GasCloudMain.onCreate

11-24 02:06:36.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1978): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nyneaxis.api.gascloud/com.nyneaxis.api.gascloud.GasCloudMain}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at com.nyneaxis.api.gascloud.GasCloudMain.onCreate(GasCloudMain.java:13)
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     ... 11 more
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.maps.MapView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44e83990
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
11-24 02:06:36.514: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
```

This is my Main class:

```
    package com.nyneaxis.api.gascloud;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class GasCloudMain extends TabActivity { 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Resources res = getResources();
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec; 
        Intent intent;

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Profile.class);

        spec = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("profile")
                .setIndicator("Profile",
                        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_profile))
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, StationsList.class);
        spec = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("stations")
                .setIndicator("Stations",
                        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_station))
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SearchStations.class);
        spec = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("search")
                .setIndicator("Search",
                        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_search))
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, StationsMap.class);
        spec = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("map")
                .setIndicator("Map",
                        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_maps))
                .setContent(new Intent(this, StationsMap.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="1dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

maps class

```
package com.nyneaxis.api.gascloud;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class StationsMap extends MapActivity  {

    LinearLayout linearLayout;
        MapView mapView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

maps.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
            <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="ABQIAAAAYc7mzgA4G-2FaBLUHTM_1xTjBItGPNb7O-Zq4IGUb6RxSdEi4RQ7Y-p4UARzkmuBTxknyrJRWOA31w"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help, I am lost to what I need to do. I can run the maps class withtout the tabs and it works. Thank you in advance. PS I have triends a few things by Googling but nothing close to what I want to accomplish.

Comment: Google API. I have tested it in the emulator and on a device. Same result.

Comment: then check this in your manifest file <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the following in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

In the `<application>` tag you should have:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Check, thanks for reminding me to check. I usually forget those things.

Comment: You've forgotton to make sure it is within the application tag of your AndroidManifest. You put it in the Manifest tag. Am i right? :)

Comment: I got the map to view in the tab and it was working fine up till today. Keep in mind I have touched any code in for the map view since I got it working. All of a sudden nothing is being view on the map view anymore, just a the map grid. What would be causing this? I have tried a new API key and it does not seem to work. Google Maps loads everything fine. I even tried it on other phones, still just a grid.

Comment: My best bet would be to make sure that your api key matches your debug key (Location of that found in Eclipse preferences). The tiles not loading is basically always because of either: Wrong permissions (Check manifest), no internet access, or an incorrect api key. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. That's how i fixed:
Put only this at your maps.xml file and should work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="ABQIAAAAYc7mzgA4G-2FaBLUHTM_1xTjBItGPNb7O-Zq4IGUb6RxSdEi4RQ7Y-p4UARzkmuBTxknyrJRWOA31w"
/>
```

**EDIT :** I also noticed this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.maps.MapView
```

Perhaps you have not download yet, the Google API. Open the SDK Manager and download the Google API, for the SDK versions that you want.

And don't forget to specify that you use the Google library. In the AndroidManifest make sure that you have

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Comment: It doesn't work either, it throws and error and breaks the code.

error: unbound prefix

Comment: @BrandonWilson ok check some other suggestions. I edited my answer

Comment: Its downloaded and it doesn't work on a device either. Gets the same error. everything checks out.

Comment: Ok, lets check something else. Write click on your project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries Tab. There should be a Google APIs option, and when you expand it should contain, android.jar and maps.jar. If maps.jar is not there, something is wrong with your project setup.